# Generalized version of open map theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Can anyone please suggest where to get the proof of the following generalized version of open map theorem: 
Let $T$ be a bounded linear map from a Banach space $X$ into a normed space $Y$. If the image $T(X)$ is non-meager in $Y$ then $T$ is surjective and an open mapping. Moreover $Y$ is complete.

Are there any other generalized versions also for the open map theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following links, good luck :)

http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/240-01-02/Lecture_Notes/current_versions/chapter16.pdf

http://planetmath.org/proofofopenmappingtheorem

http://people.math.sc.edu/schep/Openmapping.pdf